# What are the consequences of changing a UserScript's @namespace key?

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts, greasemonkey-4

I want to move some userscripts from greasyfork.org and openuserjs.org to GitHub.

Currently I'm updating the scripts manually on both sites, but I read up about the `@downloadURL` and `@updateURL` keys, so managing updates in one place at GitHub seems like the way to go.

I'm a bit uncertain about the `@namespace` key, which I'd like to change pointing to my GitHub URL, as I read that changing that key will prevent existing users from updating in the future, as it technically creates a new, second script.

**What I plan to do:**

1. Set up all userscripts on GitHub
2. Add the GitHub `@downloadURL` and `@updateURL` keys to the scripts currently on greasyfork and openuserjs
3. With the next update change the `@namespace` key to the GitHub URL

**My question:**

Will this approach prevent un-syncing and allow for a smooth transition for existing installations?

Comment: Sounds like something you'll have to test yourself for reliability anyway.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sure, I was just wondering if anyone who already made the switch could share some insights. If I don't get an answer I'll test it myself and share my findings in an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The `@namespace` value is combined with the `@name` value to become the unique identifier of the script [(GreaseSpot Wiki)](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#@namespace).

Different userscript managers might react differently to either of these values being changed. This appears to be an implementation-specific detail.